# Evenly sized buttons in CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I'm trying to create evenly sized CSS button links. I have 15 buttons arranged 3x5 in a table. They look great except the first column of buttons is wider than the other 2 because one of the buttons has a longer text.

The HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""><div class="btn">Flash</div></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><div class="btn">Photoshop</div></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><div class="btn">Fireworks</div></a></td>
    </tr>
```

The CSS:

```
.btn {
    width:100%;  
    padding: 3px 0px;
    background-color: grey; 
    text-align: center; 
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    bottom:3px;
    right:2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px black; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px black; 
    box-shadow: 1px 2px black; }
```

Does anyone have a solution that will force all buttons to be the same size without fixing the width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just give your `td`s a percentage width:

```
td {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: You should accept the answer and give him credit if this answer worked for you.